# How to override/replace string on target input with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 input boxes. 1=original, 2=result. I want to replace the space in the `#box2` with "-" (dash).

So I have:

```js
$("#box1").on('input', function() {
  var stts = $(this).val();
  dashed = stts.replace(/ /g, "-");
  $("#box2").val(dashed);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="box1" placeholder="original" />
<input type="text" id="box2" placeholder="dashed string" />
```

But the problem is when the original `box1` having "-" inside. When a space is pressed. There're double dashed "--" in the destination.

**The question is** : how to override the original "-" (dash). So it have only one "-" inside the destination? - https://jsfiddle.net/kcsyjrmL/

Working here : https://jsfiddle.net/kcsyjrmL/4/ (thnx to gurvinder372)

Working2 : https://jsfiddle.net/kcsyjrmL/5/ (thanx to Jp Mohan, fixing space-space)

Comment: Please dont update your question with an answer that has been provided. It causes issues with the context of your question and takes away from answers that have been provided below. Accept an answer but leave the original question intact unless required to make it clearer

Answer (score 3):

> how to override the original "-" (dash). So it have only one "-"
>   inside the destination?

Replace space with `\s+`

```
dashed = stts.replace(/(\s|\-)+/g, "-");
```

**Demo**

```js
$("#box1").on('input', function() {
  var stts = $(this).val();
  dashed = stts.replace(/(\s|\-)+/g, "-");
  $("#box2").val(dashed); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="box1" placeholder="original" />
<input type="text" id="box2" placeholder="dashed string" />
```

Comment: Thanks a million!

Comment: It's seem to have a further fix. When I pressed " - " (space-space) it come up with "---" (triple dashes). How to fix, please?

Comment: Why would you use `bind()` instead of `on()`? bind was deprecated back in 3.0. Even OP is using the `on()` function.

Comment: @MasterYoda I took it from OP's fiddle.

Comment: @gurvinder372 Looks like OP has edited their question... This is exactly why askers shouldnt update questions with answers, it totally changes the context of the question for other readers.

Comment: @MasterYoda I have used `on` anyways now. Agree with you on - not changing their own code while the question is not closed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

This will make sure multiple adjacent occurences of '-' will be made to a single '-'

```
dashed =stts.replace(/ /g,"-").replace(/--+/g, '-');
```